# Editing an InputField on mobile with the keypad open, it wont let me edit another field without loosing focus on the current 1st. How to by pass?

Tags: unity, gui, unity-ui

When I'm typing into a tmp input field on a mobile keypad, I can't instantly edit another input field by clicking it!? I have to click off the keypad to loose focus on the current before I can click on another field to open the keypad again and edit it. How can I bypass this? And go straight from one edit to another. It seems no IPointer events can be detected on another field if the focus is currently preoccupied with an inputfield already. I need two clicks, one off the keypad somewhere on the screen and then another on another field to open that one. But I only want one here.. So I don't know what to do. Any ideas? Thanks.